# Heroku - deploying fails for some reason

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

So I have this app here: [enter link description here](https://github.com/Veske/form)

And when I deploy it and open the page, I get this error:

> We're sorry, but something went wrong.
>
> If you are the application owner check the logs for more information.

It should not be because of DB type I use, I have set it to use pg when in production. Also, I have no idea where to find thoes logs in heroku..

Comment: I believe its heroku run logs

Comment: Or rather `heroku logs`.

Comment: `heroku logs` will show you your log output. I suspect you've not done `heroku run rake db:migrate` as a guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can show the full server logs from heroku with

```
heroku logs
```

from the root folder of your application. Morover with

```
heroku logs -t
```

you'll be able to see those log in real-time.

Be sure to run

```
heroku run rake db:migrate
```

when you first install the application to make sure that the database is correctly setup.

Comment: heroku run rake db:migrate was what i forgot :D